# Showing linked table items in a controller/view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a room class, which has 3 linked tables, `Property`, `Sex` (as in Male/Female), `Stage`.

I can get the `Index` controller to return the linked table items, by using `Include`:

```
var rooms = db.Rooms.Include(r => r.Property).Include(r => r.Sex).Include(r => r.Stage);
```

What I don't know is, how to you include these linked table items in the `Details` controller:

```
Room room = db.Rooms.Find(id);
```

The full controllers are listed below:

```
    //
    // GET: /Room/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var rooms = db.Rooms.Include(r => r.Property).Include(r => r.Sex).Include(r => r.Stage);
        return View(rooms.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Room/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Room room = db.Rooms.Find(id);
        if (room == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(room);
    }
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After *Include* statments you could use LINQ's *SingleOrDefault* method
Like this:

```
Room room = db.Rooms.Include(r => r.Property)
        .Include(r => r.Sex)
        .Include(r => r.Stage)
        .SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id = id);
```